# How to execute the callback at the end of the function calling it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

In my Node js application I have a function that reads line by line from a file, stores the contents of the file in an array and then calls a callback function with the array passed to the callback.

```
function readFile(callback)
{
    var fs = require('fs'), readline = require('readline');

    var rd = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('./file.txt'),
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });

    var data = [];

    rd.on('line', function(line) {
        data.push(line);
    });

    callback(data);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that `readFile` is running the callback before the file is read and the `data` array is filled. So the callback is running with an empty array. How can I make it run once the array is fully filled? Thanks.

Comment: something like `rd.on('close', function() { callback(data); })`

Comment: How do you know that it's "fully" filled? There should be an event for that - just hook your callback upon it.

Comment: look at the documentation - https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_events

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "close" event was all I needed.

Comment: @JaromandaX Why don't you put your answer as an actual answer instead of a comment? Question can't be marked as answered without an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readline has a [close](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) event which is fired on "end"

So, your code should be

```
function readFile(callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'), readline = require('readline');

    var rd = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('./file.txt'),
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });

    var data = [];

    rd.on('line', function(line) {
        data.push(line);
    }).on('close', function () {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

in **ES2015:**

```
function readFile(callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'), readline = require('readline');

    var rd = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('./file.txt'),
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });

    var data = [];

    rd.on('line', line => data.push(line)).on('close', () => callback(data));
}
```

or even

```
function readFile(callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'), 
        readline = require('readline'),
        data = [];

    readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('./file.txt'),
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    })
    .on('line', line => data.push(line))
    .on('close', () => callback(data));
}
```

but I'm not sure which of the two ES2015 codes is more readable